# Set Origin to geometry not available

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, import

I am reading a book called: [Blender Game Engine Beginner Guide](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/blender-game-engine-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide) by Victor Kuller Bacone, from Packt publishing, in which there is an exercise which directs to download from the 3D Warehouse a boat in sketchup format. The next instruction is to export the boat to Collada format, and import it into Blender. In blender, the user is instructed to use *Tools > Edit > Set Origin* and choose *Center of Mass*. When I follow those instructions, the boat object is centered. But when I try the next series of steps, downloading a [killer whale (orca whale)](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model.html?id=68b497e61a3392da3c3be2f0ebb0c535) from the same website into  Sketchup, exporting it to Collada, and import it into Blender, I don't see the menu option *Tools > Edit > Set Origin*. The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> doesn't seem to work either. Why can't the option for setting the origin to the center of mass work after importing the Orca?

I am using Sketchup version Make 2014 14.0.4900. Whether I choose from sketchup the "fix it" or "fix it later" options on exporting, I get the same error.

[image: here]

Comment: most likely you don't have the whale selected, but an Empty or something, can you show a screenshot of the outliner (the panel on the top right of this screen... it will show all objects, and which object is currently selected

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows an object origin at the center of the mesh, with a dotted line to the Orca. If I add an empty to the default scene, and define that empty as a parent of the default cube, I get a dotted line from the empty to the cube much like the line shown in the screenshot. If I select the empty object, the "Set origin" button disappears from the tool shelf. This suggests to me that you don't have the Orca selected, but instead have selected the empty.